# Using proxy to cache expensive outgoing HTTP requests?

Tags: http, caching, nginx, proxy, varnish

I am using a fairly expensive external API (there's a cost per request) which makes testing code which uses it impractical.

In an ideal world, I would have a proxy server I would do my requests against which would cache each request (based on URL + query string) indefinitely and only hit the actual API server when I explicitly invalidate the cache for a given request. Is such a server available off the shelf with minimal configuration?

My current stack is Node.js, Docker, Nginx, PostgreSQL & AWS S3 (for non ephemeral state). I think Varnish might accomplish what I need but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is that API not providing a free-of-charge testing ground?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately... :/

Comment: It sounds as if it should work - otherwise look into memcached - it does quite exactly that...

Answer (score 0):

Varnish can and will accomplish that, but only if you build a 'test' API that returns some similar data you can play with. Your best bet if you have to save money, is to query the API a few times to get different typical responses. Once you know the ballpark of what to expect from it, create some sort of dummy API, or even some static JSON or XML files that you can use to mimic it. At that point you can test Varnish and Cache invalidation, and I'd be more than happy to help you with the syntax for that, given some examples of the code.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing a library which "memoizes"/caches the client side API calls to AWS S3. Just open sourced it actually https://github.com/blockai/persistent-memoize